# Getting into android networking, HTTP library preference?

Tags: android, http, client, request

I'm finding at least 3 different ways to submit an HTTP request from an Android application.

They are:

1. The obvious Android.net.http [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html#lfields)
2. The Apache library [org.apache.http.client.HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)
3. The Java.net [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)

Which one should I use for an application that wants to get JSON server database results for later parsing? Is any one faster? What are the advantages to each? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first and second are the same. `AndroidHttpClient` is simply an implementation of the `HttpClient` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to use the Android option. The Android developers made things like that to try to simplify tasks that would normally be more difficult than needed if you used the Apache and Java options. That's just what I would do though. If you're more comfortable with something else you can always try that out? Up to you though. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

You should use HttpUrlConnection. The android team plans to support it better in the future. But don't just take my word for it: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using an [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) for a simple resource grab.

This class is very versatile and can handle HTTPS, HTTP Authentication, POSTing, cookies, and a number of other useful traits for HTTP calls. The android developer documentation on HttpURLConnections linked above provides some good examples on how to use the class properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this library: http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?p=490

Answer (score 0):

If you want websocket support and async then a good choice is also:

https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client